# Creating instance from image: INTERNAL_ERROR: Code: '4E26EF2CD2449-1DEDB67B'

Tags: google-compute-engine

Trying to import an OS image from the outside - have succeeded in some cases. 
On one of my disk image instantiation attempts I am getting:

```
operation-1374865750495-4e26ee0aaee09-f1944825 Error    
INTERNAL_ERROR: Code: '4E26EF2CD2449-1DEDB67B' Operation Type   
Insert Target Type
```

Comment: Please add more details about the disk image that is failing if they are relevant to the issue - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: 12gig, single partition, primary, ext3 filesystem.
My guess is the error comes before the OS gets started, but FWIW the OS is RHEL 6.2

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating this instance using a scratch disk or a persistent disk for the root volume?

I think there's a limit of 10GB for images used with a scratch root disk. You might try creating a persistent disk from that image and then launch the instance using the persistent disk as the root volume.